# Add selectbox from Directives controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options

I am trying to dynamicaly add select box from directive. the same ng option works perfectly without directive but from directive it gives empty list . please check below fiddle.

**I dont want to put selectbox in Directive template ... i need to add them from controller only..**

**Fiddle::**
http://jsfiddle.net/NfPcH/2009/

**Code:**

```
<select ng-model="selectedOption" ng-options="option for option in [1,2,3,45,6,8,9,7]"></select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to solve your problem is to use the directive `compile` function (read ['Compilation process, and directive matching' and 'Compile function'](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)) to modify elements before its compilation.

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NfPcH/2012/)**

```
app.directive('hello', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {},
        template: 'hello world',
        controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs, $compile) {
            var el = angular.element('<select ng-model="selectedOption" ng-options="option for option in [1,2,3,45,6,8,9,7]"></select>');
            $compile(el)($scope);
            $element.append(el);
        },
    }
});
```

Comment: i need to add them from controller ony ... it is not part of template